# I am not able to write author^a in the authors name and link for latex file is https://www.overleaf.com/5976456653rptbqrnpjhjx

Tags: titles, journal-publishing, author-number

I cannot write author^a in the author's name, and the link for the latex file is https://www.overleaf.com/5976456653rptbqrnpjhjx. The image is also attached.

[image]

Comment: Please provide small but complete document in your question.. Your link can after while  become dead and your problem the readers then will not be able to reproduce.

Comment: Please don't post a link to a file which may or may not disappear soon, rendering your posting useless to future readers. Moreover, people without an Overleaf account can't access the link you've provided. Hence, do please post the code here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to be using [Elsevier's template for articles](https://www.latextemplates.com/template/elseviers-elsarticle-document-class), which LaTeX instructions are given [here](https://www.elsevier.com/authors/policies-and-guidelines/latex-instructions), and mention the following (directly in the LaTeX file, `ecrc-template.tex`):

```
%% Title, authors and addresses
%% use the tnoteref command within \title for footnotes;
%% use the tnotetext command for the associated footnote;
%% use the fnref command within \author or \address for footnotes;
%% use the fntext command for the associated footnote;
%% use the corref command within \author for corresponding author footnotes;
%% use the cortext command for the associated footnote;
%% use the ead command for the email address,
%% and the form \ead[url] for the home page:
%%
%% \title{Title\tnoteref{label1}}
%% \tnotetext[label1]{}
%% \author{Name\corref{cor1}\fnref{label2}}
%% \ead{email address}
%% \ead[url]{home page}
%% \fntext[label2]{}
%% \cortext[cor1]{}
%% \address{Address\fnref{label3}}
%% \fntext[label3]{}
```

(Which seems to have been deleted from the template you are using in overleaf).

The following fragment produces the desired output in the overleaf you point to.

```
\title{Title of paper}

\author{First Author\corref{cor1}}
\ead{email address}
\ead[url]{home page}
\cortext[cor1]{Corresponding Author}
\address{Address of first author}

\author{Second Author}
\ead{email address}
\ead[url]{home page}
\address{Address of second author}
```

I hope it helps!